# Do while loop not working in Method that uses random intergers to simulate dice roll

Tags: c#

I am working on a Dice simulator in C# and my do while loop is not working as I would expect. I have it commented out currently but without it the result of the dice simulator method is always returning "2" (because the do/while is not checking whether or the sum of the die is equal to the user input). Would anyone be willing to help a novice correct the code so that the program functions properly?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
//Begin Program

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int DiceRollSim(int input)
        {
            Random dice1 = new Random();
            Random dice2 = new Random();

            int sum = dice1.Next(1, 7) + dice2.Next(1, 7);
            int count = 1;

           /* do
            {*/
                {
                    sum = dice1.Next(1, 7) + dice2.Next(1, 7);
                    count++;
                }

           /* } while (sum != input);*/

            return count;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello! This program rolls a pair of die until the sum of the die is equal to your given number.\n\n");

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 2 and 12: ");
            int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int rolls = DiceRollSim(num);
            int[] array_possiblesum = new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };

            if (Array.IndexOf(array_possiblesum, num) > -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n Congratulations! It took " + rolls + " rolls of the die for them to equal your entry, " + num + ".");
            }
            else 
            {
                Random newnum = new Random();
                num = newnum.Next(2, 13);
                int roll2 = DiceRollSim(num);

                Console.WriteLine("\n\n I'm sorry! Your input was not valid     so we chose a new number for you. The number we chose is:" + num+".");
                Console.WriteLine(" \n\n It took " + roll2 + " rolls of the die for them to equal your entry, " + num + ".");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Watch out: When you instantiate two Random classes at the same time, they usually give the *same* list of "random" numbers. Which means you only roll even numbers.

Comment: When the user inputs an invalid number, your code will call DiceRollSim anyway. (and what if an evil user inputs "A"?)

Comment: What is the point of initializing `sum`, if you override it anyway in the loop? Is it a remnant of previously (possibly) used `while` loop?

Answer (score 2):

You create two instances of Random at (more or less) the same time. The [documentation of Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers.

So dice1.Next() and dice2.Next() will always return the same value and if input is not divisble by two the loop will run forever.

Simply use one instance for both dice. You don't need to have two instances of the Random class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two Random classes, and having two is significantly *less* random than one.  Also, you shouldn't be re-instantiating your Random class every time, just instantiate it once at the beginning.

So try you class like this:

```
class Program
{
    Random dice1 = new Random();

    static int DiceRollSim(int input)
    {

        int sum = dice1.Next(1, 7) + dice1.Next(1, 7);
        int count = 1;

       /* do
        {*/
            {
                sum = dice1.Next(1, 7) + dice1.Next(1, 7);
                count++;
            }

       /* } while (sum != input);*/

        return count;
    }
```